# WPF Bind RowDefinition.Height property to another RowDefinition with Height=Auto within DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to make 3 rows in a grid in a WPF datatemplate. The first is set to Height=Auto, the second fills the available space and the third is equal to the first. I've tried with binding to elementname, but that doesn't seem to work

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="definition" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=definition, Path=ActualHeight}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Height="100" />
</Grid>
```

In this example I hope the height of the third row is also 100px. Any suggestions?

Comment: Auto means fit to content....you havent added control content in row0 so its actualheight is 0 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Height="100" Background="Red" x:Name="definition"/>
    <Grid Background="Green" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2" Height="{Binding ElementName=definition, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

`RowDefinition.ActualHeight` is not an actually dependency property, which means your binding won't get any "updates" about `ActualHeight` being changed.

You can follow this pattern:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ElementName=FirstRow, Path=ActualHeight}" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="FirstRow" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SecondRow" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ThirdRow" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The reason this should work theoretically, is simple enough: `RowDefinition.ActualHeight == FirstRow.ActualHeight` (by default it should fill available space)

Alternatively, just steal the RowDefinition, and perhaps create your own CustomRowDefinition which can implement dependency property, called `ActualHeight`, and fire updates.

http://dotnetinside.com/in/type/PresentationFramework/RowDefinition/4.0.0.0